# Instantiate different classes with the same name/namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I have an architecture consisting of two DLLs and one executable. Both DLLs define a class with the same name and namespace, but potentially different implementations. What I would like to do is to create an object of each of those classes, and have both of them coexist at the same time.

But as we know a picture says more than a thousand words, so here you go:
[image: Architecture overview]

The surprising thing is: it actually seems to work!
I have implemented a small prototype using lots of reflection to load the DLLs and instantiate the objects.

Now my question is: **Why does this work?**
Shouldn't there be a problem having both of the classes in the same AppDomain?
Is it safe to do it this way, or did I just get lucky?

Comment: Keyword being "assembly qualified name". That you can't do it from C# by typing the class name, doesn't mean that the runtime can't do it.

Comment: aside: please avoid namespace/typename collisions. they will cause a lot of headaches later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type is more than its class name and namespace. It also includes assembly information to qualify it. You can compare the [`AssemblyQualifiedName` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) of any `System.Type` and see that they are different.